# Проверить корректность контрольной суммы. (Газпромовская задача для 10 класса по информатике)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Во время проведения бухгалтерского отчета по предприятию, произошел
сбой при передаче данных по затратам подразделений. Предприятие имеет 10
подразделений. Известно, что затраты каждого подразделения не превышают
500 млн. рублей и контрольная сумма SUM.

Контрольная сумма удовлетворяет следующим условиям:

1. SUM — произведение затрат от двух подразделений.
2. SUM делится на 14.

Если контрольной суммы, удовлетворяющей условиям, нет, то значения
не корректны и бухгалтерский отчет не сформирован.

Напишите эффективную программу, проверяющую корректность контрольной суммы.

Программа должна напечатать отчёт по следующей форме:

> Контрольная сумма: ... Отчет сформирован. (или — Отчет не сформирован)

Кратко опишите используемый алгоритм решения.
На вход программе в каждой строке подаются затраты подразделений в
млн. рублей (натуральные числа, не превышающее 500). В последней строке
записана контрольная сумма.

```
Пример входных данных:
12
32
18
18
64
14
7
9
49
10
168
```

Пример выходных данных для приведённого выше примера входных
данных:
Контрольная сумма:168

Собственно задача,я не прошу ее решать ,мне требуется помощь в понимании концепции

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно в концепции? Как нам угадать то место, которое вам непонятно?

Comment: @AK это олимпиадная задачка для 10 класса,причем тут задание на собеседовании ??)
за правку спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, газпромовцы имели ввиду, что:

1 - Проверь, что контрольная сумма делится на 14 без остатка. Тут достаточно взять саму контрольную сумму и проверить деление на 14. Контрольную сумму мы же знаем, потому что `В последней строке записана контрольная сумма.`

Если число делится на 14, то дальше
2 - Делим контрольную сумму на затраты в каждом подразделении и проверяем:
а) Делится без остатка
б) Есть ли такое подразделение (кроме делителя), которое равно частному. [немного напоминалки из школы: Делимое / делитель = частное]

На примере:

1 - 168 делится на 14. Значит можно переходить к пункту 2

Допустим дошли по затратам до строчки `14`.

2 - 168 разделить на 14 равно 12.
а) 168 разделилось на 14 **без остатка** 
б) Есть такое подразделение, в котором затраты равно 12 (первая строка)